# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS and C++11

Tags: c++, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is C++11 currently supported by ROS? If not is this support planned for the near future?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12227/ros-and-c++11/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP 3](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#c):

"We use the C++03 (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) standard, and are compiler-agnostic. While we mainly develop with gcc, no use of compiler-specific features is allowed without proper use of macros to allow use on other platforms.

Use of C++[0|1]x or tr1 features are only allowed if support for that feature is checked at compile time, and equivalent functionality exists without requiring C++[0|1]x code. A wholesale jump to C++[0|1]x will not happen until all commonly used OS platforms fully support it."

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-01-21**:
is it still the case (13 months later)?

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2016-11-28**:
Distributions up to Jade use C++03, but Kinetic uses C++11. http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html